# Editing Multiple .php files using PHP

Tags: php, file, edit

I want to edit 100  php files in different folders using php.
I have searched on google but doesn't get any help.
I want to replace some text with other text on every file. Tell me a suitable way to do it using php.

For eg. I have two texts t1 ,t2 and i want to replace it with v1,v2 in every file how to do it?.

Comment: I'd probably use `sed` on the command line, but you run the risk of making unexpected changes if you are not careful. Alternatively, let your tools do the heavy lifting: have a look at your favourite IDE/file editor - it might have multi-file search and replace? For instance, Sublime Text has `Find in Files..` feature that allows multi-file search and replace, optionally with regex pattern matching.  As advised below, I would take an incremental approach - do not blindly run a destructive process on your files!

Answer (score 1):

1. PHP is really not the best tool for the job... but it can do it. [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) is probably better-suited but definitely has a bit of a learning curve.
2. You're going to want to use the following functions:

   - [opendir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)
   - [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
   - You'll be iterating over each file using a `for` loop and performing the `str_replace()` on each file. **I recommend not just doing this blindly as it could be very destructive if you make a mistake.**

If you've tried this and have a specific problem, come back and post that along with what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = array(
    'directory/file1.php',
    'directory/file2.php'
)

$t1 = 'your text 1';
$t2 = 'your text 2';

$t1 = 'your version 1';
$t2 = 'your version 2';

foreach($files as $f) {
   $old_content = file_get_contents($f);
   $new_content = str_replace($t1, $v1, $old_content);
   $new_content = str_replace($t2, $v2, $new_content);
   file_put_contents($f, $new_content);
}
```

Comment: First i tried this put it don't able to do my work. Now looking at ur code i get what i want. Thanks i will modiy it.
My code:
   <?php
   foreach(glob("path/to/files/*.txt") as $filename)
   {
   $file = file_get_contents($filename);
   file_put_contents($filename,preg_replace("/regexhere/","replacement",$file));
   }
?>
 the problem with above code is that i can perform only one replacement but i have to make many replacement. Now i can do it by checking your code. Thank you for help.

Comment: I think that str_replace (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is the best way to do it.